# Cross Platform AES Encryption for .NET WCF, .NET CF, Android, Symbian

Tags: .net, android, encryption, compact-framework, symbian

I have WCF services hosted on server that needs to accept encrypted value from various mobile platforms like Windows Mobile, Symbian, Android, BlackBerry, iPhone etc.

I am unable to get the cross platform AES encryption implementation (most of the time I am getting Padding is invalid and cannot be removed error) for .NET and all other mobile platforms.

Anyone who had developed such encryption solution that will work for .NET, .NET CF, Android, Symbian, BlackBerry, iPhone etc?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bouncy Castle C# Cryptography APIs](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/). It has pretty much everything you need and will work with above platforms (save Symbian and BB).

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents for .Net, CF, Android & Spring WebServices :

I was able to make things work with AES + CBC + PKCS5Padding

In .Net CF, you can find System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged (You have to set the block size set to 128, it is important).

Comment: The problem with RijndaelManaged is that it uses PasswordDerivedBytes from System.Security.Cryptography which is not available in .NET CF. I tried to use it from OpenNETCF, but it gives different result from System.Security.Cryptography. I am able to use OpenNETCF on Server (.NET) and .NET CF and it worked. But, for other mobile platforms, it's not working.

Comment: But it exists in Mono. Few adaptations make it work on the CF 2.0.       Sorry I forgot that step :/     
Or you can have a look at bouncycastle [link](http://www.bouncycastle.org/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will look in to it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Few important things to note while implementing AES encryption:
1. Never use plain text as encryption key. Always hash the plain text key and then use for encryption.
2. Always use Random IV (initialization vector) for encryption and decryption. True randomization is important.

I recently wrote cross platform AES encryption and decryption library for C#, iOS and Android which I have posted on Github. You can see it here - https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption

Comment: I tried the Library for iOS and  C# .while passing data from mobile to backend + sign are Disappearing and space is added for the encrypted text.

Comment: while decrypting the bulk data first 16 bits of data are  still in encrypted format and other data are getting decrypted.

Comment: some problem occurs while encrypting and decrypting data in C#